# ComponentDidUpdate causing infinite render even when wrapped in condition

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pull some data from Google Analytics reporting API and display the data inside the apex charts library. I managed to successfully do this. However, I now want filtering options to where if the user selects a certain date within the date range picker react wrapper, the apex charts data gets updated from the API.

I'm struggling figuring out on how when my data gets updated, to update the state with the new state within my life cycle method? I think I'm doing something minor I just don't know what it is. I looked up the documentation on the life cycle method and it says to make sure to wrap it inside a condition which I did. However, when the else condition is met, it causes an infinite render.

Here is my code: (the bug i'm stuck on is the componentWillUpdate lifecycle method) everything else works fine.

```js
import React from "react";

import Header from "../common/Header";
import Footer from "../common/Footer";

import moment from "moment";
import $ from "jquery";
import ApexCharts from "apexcharts";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";
import DateRangePicker from "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker";

const VIEW_ID = "";

class Charts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.printResults = this.printResults.bind(this);
    this.pageViews = this.pageViews.bind(this);
    this.handleError = this.handleError.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      filterstartDate: "",
      filterendDate: "",
      // Start Series Bar State

      ChartOne: {
        chart: {
          id: "ChartOne"
        },
        colors: ["#e31d1a"],
        xaxis: {
          categories: [],
          labels: {
            style: {
              colors: []
            }
          },
          title: {
            text: "Locations"
          }
        },
        yaxis: {
          labels: {
            style: {
              colors: []
            }
          },
          title: {
            text: "Count"
          }
        }
      },
      ChartOneSeries: [],
  }

  pageViews = async () => {
    window.gapi.client
      .request({
        path: "/v4/reports:batchGet",
        root: "https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com",
        method: "POST",
        body: {
          reportRequests: [
            {
              viewId: VIEW_ID,
              dateRanges: [
                {
                  startDate: "7daysAgo",
                  endDate: "today"
                }
              ],
              metrics: [
                {
                  expression: "ga:pageviews"
                }
              ],
              dimensions: [
                {
                  name: "ga:country"
                }
              ],
              orderBys: [{ fieldName: "ga:pageviews", sortOrder: "DESCENDING" }]
            }
          ]
        }
      })
      .then(this.printResults, this.handleError);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    $.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js").done(() => {
      window.gapi.signin2.render("my-signin2", {
        scope: "profile email",
        width: 240,
        height: 50,
        longtitle: true,
        theme: "dark",
        onsuccess: this.pageViews,
        onfailure: this.handleError
      });
    });
  }

  //log the data
  printResults(response) {
    let pageviewLocation = [];
    let pageviewCount = [];
    let pageviewTotal = response.result.reports[0].data.totals[0].values[0];
    let totalComma = pageviewTotal
      .toString()
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

    response.result.reports[0].data.rows.map(value => {
      //console.log(value.dimensions);
      pageviewLocation.push(value.dimensions[0]);
      pageviewCount.push(parseInt(value.metrics[0].values[0]));
    });

    //console.log(total);

    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      ChartOne: {
        title: {
          text: totalComma,
          align: "center",
          style: {
            fontSize: "20px"
          }
        },
        subtitle: {
          text: "Total Page Views",
          align: "center",
          style: {
            fontSize: "14px",
            cssClass: "apexcharts-yaxis-title"
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {},
        ...this.state.ChartOne,
        xaxis: {
          width: 1,
          ...this.state.ChartOne.xaxis,
          labels: {
            show: false,
            ...this.state.ChartOne.xaxis.labels,
            style: {
              ...this.state.ChartOne.xaxis.labels.style
            }
          },
          categories: pageviewLocation
        },
        yaxis: {
          min: 0,
          ...this.state.ChartOne.yaxis,
          labels: {
            //show: false,
            ...this.state.ChartOne.yaxis.labels,
            style: {
              ...this.state.ChartOne.yaxis.labels.style
            }
          }
        }
      },
      ChartOneSeries: [
        {
          name: "Total Page Views",
          data: pageviewCount
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.filterstartDate === "" && this.state.filterendDate === "") {
      console.log("they are empty");
    } else {
      this.setState({
        // this fails immediately once the condition is met
        test: "success!"
      });
    }
  }

  Datepicker = async (event, picker) => {
    this.setState({
      filterstartDate: moment(picker.startDate._d).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      filterendDate: moment(picker.endDate._d).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    });

    //console.log(this.state);
  };

  //or the error if there is one
  handleError(reason) {
    console.error(reason);
    console.error(reason.result.error.message);
  }

  render() {
    //console.log();

    return (
      <div className="containerfluid" id="fullWidth">
        <Header />
        <div className="container" id="chartContainer">
          <h1>Site Analytics</h1>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <DateRangePicker
                startDate={moment().format("MM-DD-YYYY")}
                endDate={moment().format("MM-DD-YYYY")}
                onApply={this.Datepicker}
              >
                <button className="btn btn-info">
                  <i className="fas fa-filter">
                    <span
                      style={{
                        fontFamily: "Roboto, san-serif",
                        fontWeight: "normal",
                        padding: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      Filter Date
                    </span>
                  </i>
                </button>
              </DateRangePicker>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4">
              {/* Chart One Line */}
              {this.state.loading ? (
                <React.Fragment>
                  <i className="fas fa-spinner fa-3x" id="loader" /> Please wait
                  ...!
                </React.Fragment>
              ) : (
                <div className="chartContainer">
                  <Chart
                    options={this.state.ChartOne}
                    series={this.state.ChartOneSeries}
                    type="line"
                    width={400}
                    height={300}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="my-signin2" />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Charts;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `setState` you're triggering the lifecycle again. If you don't set your `filterstartDate` and `filterendDate` to `""`, you'll keep calling setState infinitely.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.filterstartDate === "" && this.state.filterendDate === "") {
      console.log("they are empty");
    } else {
      this.setState({
        filterstartDate: "",
        filterendDate: "",
        test: "success!"
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. This seemed to fix the solution. However, I found out I don't need componentDidUpdate I just attached a event handler to the date picker and I can now update the chart from the api no problem. Thanks for this I'll take it into consideration in the future. Out of all the lifecycle methods this one confuses me the most. Seems like i need more practice with it...